# What is the way to point on class "this" from a class ajaxSuccess event listener method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, this

I found a quick solution in my app to refresh the content on any change - ajaxSuccess(), but I can not figure out, how to bind "this" not to the event.target...

The bind() method worked just fine for a usual eventListener, but it does not work with ajaxSuccess, and this problem keeps me awake for 2 days.

```
class DataManager {

    constructor() {
        this.data = [];
        this.ajaxSuccessListener().bind(this); // not working as it should;
    }

    ajaxSuccessListener() {
        $(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, request, settings) {
            if (settings.type !== "GET") {
                this.refresh();
            }
        })
    }

    refresh() {
        // refreshes the content
    }
}
```

I expect to run class refresh() method whenever a http request, that is not a "GET" is made. If there is a problem with the ajaxSuccess() itself, may be there is another elegant solution?

Comment: You are calling the function here `this.ajaxSuccessListener().bind(this)` but `ajaxSuccessListener` doesn't `return` anything, so it returns `undefined`, and you try to bind `undefined` which doesn't work.

Comment: `ajaxSuccessListener` doesn't appear to be a listener at all (show us how you are calling it!)? The listener that you will need to `.bind()` is the `function` that you are passing to `ajaxSuccess(…)`.

Comment: You could solve your problem by removing bind and in `ajaxSuccessListener` save `this` before calling `ajaxSuccess` like `const that = this`;

Comment: Why don't you pass a callback?constructor() {
        this.data = [];
        this.ajaxSuccessListener(this.refresh); // no need of binding
    }

    ajaxSuccessListener(cb) {
        $(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, request, settings) {
            if (settings.type !== "GET") {
                cb();
            }
        })
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a JavaScript class, you can use implicit binding via the arrow function:

```
class DataManager {

    constructor() {
        this.data = [];
    }

    // ajaxSuccessListener() {
    // () => {} implicitly binds to "this"
    ajaxSuccessListener = () => {
        $(document).ajaxSuccess(function (event, request, settings) {
            if (settings.type !== "GET") {
                // "this" now refers to the instance of "DataManager"
                this.refresh();
            }
        })
    }

    refresh() {
        // refreshes the content
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't try running any of this code, just pointing out how arrow functions will give you what you've specifically asked for. As other have mentioned, I don't see in your code how `ajaxSuccessListener()` ever gets called...

Comment: Thank You, this would be the most elegant solution!
P.S. ajaxSuccess is called, whenever a ajax request is successful in the document